# sql select duplicate records once

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

Lets say I have 5 rows with the same data

```
|id|
 --
|1 |
 --
|1 |
 --
|1 |
 -- 
|1 |
```

if I echo those results out I'm gonna get 1111 but I only want to select duplicate records one, so instead I would get 1.

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY id;` in your mysql statement

Although I am not sure why you have duplicate IDs in your database -- that should be remedied.

Answer (score 3):

You can either `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove rows in the result that have all columns the same or you can `GROUP BY` the columns you want to select which is useful if you want to get a count of the rows that have duplicates.

Comment: ``DISTICT`` should be ``DISTINCT``

Answer (score 2):

```
GROUP BY id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) from table
```