# PHP and SQL - Search joined table and get single result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, phpmyadmin

The SQL code I use:

```
SELECT band.bands, udgivelser.udgivelser, numre.numre 
FROM diskografi
AS diskografi
INNER JOIN band 
AS band 
ON diskografi.FKband = band.id
INNER JOIN udgivelser
AS udgivelser
ON diskografi.FKudgivelser = udgivelser.id
INNER JOIN numre
AS numre
ON diskografi.FKnumre = numre.id
```

Gives me following table:

```
bands    | udgivelser  | numre
---------+-------------+---------
Muse     | Showbiz     | Sunburn
Muse     | Showbiz     | Muscle Museum
etc.
```

I used following PHP code for the search function:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$query = mysql_query("SQL FROM ABOVE INSERTED HERE 
                          WHERE band.bands 
                      LIKE '%$searchq%'") 
              or die("fejl i søgning!");

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output == 'Der var ingen søgeresultater!';
}else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $fband = $row['bands'];
        $id = $row['ID'];

        $output .= '<div> '.$fband.' </div>';
```

First of all, I want to be able to search through the table, but only get the result to show up once. I also want it to work in such away that when you search for things in the tables `udgivelser` and `numre`, it will show the `bands` instead. 
For example if I search for `Showbiz` it will write out `Muse` a single time.

**EDIT :**
[using this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559371/sql-select-duplicate-records-once) After intense searching I found an answer to my first question. I still however, want to be able to search for `udgivelser` and `numre`, but get the `bands` as an result.

I added `GROUP BY id` after this string

```
SQL FROM ABOVE INSERTED HERE 
WHERE band.bands
LIKE '%$searchq%'
GROUP BY band.bands
```

Comment: Well, not a fix, but an explanation; looks like your problem may be that you're adding a `WHERE` after a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That made me able to search at least. Thank you!

Comment: If you want search for `udgivelser` and `numre` you just need to extend your where clause with something like `OR udgivelser.<your field> LIKE '%$searchq%'`.
I do not know how big your database is - and this might be a bit out of topic, but try to get more informations about SolR and Lucine Search :)

Comment: @Jurik It's a school project, so starting from scratch as far as I can. The `OR` statement worked, so thanks.

Comment: Okay, than SolR and Lucine Search would be a 'little' bit over engineering ;)